# Making Boolean mask on date column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, compare

Letsay I have a DataFrame with badly formatted dates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['01-01-1980','2001-03-01','05/22/2020'],columns=['DATE'])
```

I want to compare them to some date '06/07/2003'. Doing Boolean mask on Timestamp-converted values is obvious way to go:

```
mask=pd.Timestamp(df['DATE']) < pd.Timestamp('06/07/2003')
```

but that does not fly because Timestamp does not understand Series object. You can go pedestrian way but that is ugly:

```
mask=pd.Series([pd.Timestamp(df.loc[x,'DATE']) for x in df['DATE'].index]) < pd.Timestamp('06/07/2003')
```

How to do it concisely?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for convert to datetimes, also for compare is possible use string:

```
mask = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']) < '06/07/2003'
print (mask)
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: DATE, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found one answer while posting - there is 'apply' function on Pandas Series class:

```
mask=df['DATE'].apply(pd.Timestamp) < pd.Timestamp('06/07/2003')
```

Comment: use `pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])` instead of `pd.Timestamp`